# In googlesheets I would like to change the value of a cell only if a condition is true otherwise keep it the same

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

In googlesheets I would like to change the value of a cell only if a condition is true otherwise keep it the same

=IF (a condition is true, new value , keep this cell unchanged)

An example of a formula in cell A1 might look like this
=IF( B1=1, B2, A1)

where B2 holds the new value to go in A1 if B1=1

However, if thisformula is entered in A1 then it gives an error.

Comment: The original value of A1 needs to be somewhere else in your sheet. As it now reads, you're having A1 reference itself which will not work. Or it needs be hardcoded in your formula. Example if A1 value should be 99.: `=IF(B1=1,B2,99)`

Comment: Share your example so we could helpe you

Comment: Thanks , but I was considering a situation where A1 references a volatile value such as Googlefinance("LON:BDEV"). If C1 held the formula =Googlefinance("LON:BDEV") and A1 held =IF(B2=1,C1, keep A1unchanged). Making B1==1 would cause A1 to hold the current price of BDEV but if B1 =0 then I would like A1 to keep that price. So it would be possible to make B1 change to 1 or 0 depending on the time and the result would be A1 holds the price at a particular time.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(B1=1; B2; A1)
```

if this still errors out for you, circle back here with the error message